# Click function is triggered, but @Output does not emit

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to set up the 'X' close button on a modal. So far I see console logs (shown below) from within the `(click)` function, but I do not get a response from the `EventEmitter`.

parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public configOpen = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doClose(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<div>
    ...page body...
<div>
<child (closeModal)="doClose($event)"></child>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doClose() {
    this.closeModal.emit("nice");
    console.log("here");
  }
}
```

child.component.html

```
<div class="header-row">
     <h6 class="title">Title</h6>
     <mat-icon class="collapse-toggle" (click)="doClose()">close</mat-icon>
</div>
```

I see the "here" `console.log` from child.component.ts `doClose()`, but I do not get "nice" from parent.component.ts. I am 85% sure I copied this accurately out of the Angular docs and none of the other SO EventEmitter questions solved my issue. Any ideas?

Edit:

I get this warning when restarting NPM:

> .../node_modules/@observablehq/plot/src/transforms/dodge.js depends on
> 'interval-tree-1d'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause
> optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Comment: Honestly, it should work. Are you sure this is all code?
Here's a stackblitz I made, with code very similar tto yours : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hsczee?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter

Comment: @MG No, but this is part of a much larger file, just copied in the relevant bits. No idea what else would cause this in the the surrounding code, though. Especially since the child half of the equation is working as expected.

Comment: @PR06GR4MM3R is there any error in browser console or warning?

Comment: Check if you have a variable name in parent that override the function "doClose", I agree that the code is correct :(

Comment: @JayPatel nope :( just no response on the parent side

Comment: @Eliseo I've tried several combinations of function and EventEmitter names and all of them behaved in the same way

Comment: @JayPatel Actually, I get two warnings like the one shown in the edit section of my question. Both regard graphing libraries that shouldn't (?) be related (?)..